# A collaborator has not contacted me besides our initial conversation, is it alright to find another?

Tags: research-process, collaboration

I am a non-thesis graduate student working on an independent research project. I contacted a professor at another university for help with using COMSOL, a modeling software. He asked if I was interested in an academic collaboration and I said yes. Since then, I presented a poster on the research I had already completed. I sent an email following up, especially since I wanted to add a future work section to the poster. I have not received a reply. At the conferect I had a lot of people interested in my work. Since it has been a couple of months since our conversation, with no follow up on the professor's end, is it alright to move on to a different collaborator? Should I follow up again?

Comment: Did you add his name to the poster as a token of collaboration? If yes, then you should follow up. If not, then that explains why you are being ghosted.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be a mistake to make assumptions here. Collaborating with such a professor is a real opportunity and you shouldn't leave hard feelings. Professors are busy, but it would be good to contact them again asking if they are still interested and asking them for their suggestion on next steps from both of you. If you have deadlines (as professors don't) say what they are.